# Power Automate to group fields by value

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I have the list as below:

List 1:

CustomerCode | CustomerName | ProductName | ProductCode | ManufactureDate | ExpiryDate | ProductPrice

*CustomerCode and CustomerName can have duplicate values

List 2:
CustomerCode | AmountPurchased

What I want to achieve:
I want to automatically populate Sharepoint List 2 with Power automate.
Condition:
CustomerCode cannot be duplicated.
I want to group List 1 by CustomerCode and add the AmountPurchased by the customer and fill in List 2.

I am new to Power Automate. Your help and assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Sum-a-column-from-one-sharepoint-list-with-a-condition-to/td-p/122078

Well documented already in this post :-)